# Input string was not in a correct format wtih cm.Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-insert, numeric, varchar

I got this error message : input string was not in a correct format

It throws this error message at these two codes:

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", double.Parse(frmCancelDetails.Instance.txtPrice.Text));
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", int.Parse(frmCancelDetails.Instance.txtQty.Text));
```

Also, when (double.Parse) and (int.Parse) are deleted, another message is thrown at the end of the code:

error converting data type varchar to numeric

Here is the full code

```
public void SaveCancelOrder(string user)       
    {
        cn.Open();
        cm = new SqlCommand("insert into tblCancel (transno, pcode, price, qty, sdate, voidby, canelledby, reason, action)values(@transno, @pcode, @price, @qty, @sdate, @voidby, @canelledby, @reason, @action)", cn);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transno"   , frmCancelDetails.Instance.txtTransNo.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode"     , frmCancelDetails.Instance.txtPcode.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price"   , double.Parse(frmCancelDetails.Instance.txtPrice.Text));
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty"       , int.Parse(frmCancelDetails.Instance.txtQty.Text));
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate"     ,  DateTime.Now);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voidby"    , user);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@canelledby", frmCancelDetails.Instance.txtCanceledBy.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reason"    , frmCancelDetails.Instance.txtReason.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action"    , frmCancelDetails.Instance.comAddToInventory.Text);
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: actually it would be amazingly helpful if you would provide the input that led to the exception. otherwise we cannot assist you much

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Check xx.Text   strings  at the point.

Comment: Seems pretty certain that either txtPrice.Text or txtQty.Text contains a non-number. What are the values of those fields just before the query runs? I would recommend switching their textboxes to be NumericUpDowns instead, and `AddWithValue( ..., xNumericUpDown.Value)`, not `.Text` - this way the user can't enter bad numeric data

Comment: And then read Dan Guzman's blog about avoiding using AddWithValue https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/ - it's not so much of an issue with an INSERT (and i'd definitely rather see AddWithValue than SQL Injection, so kudos for that one), but it can really clobber performance if you use it with parameters in a WHERE clause

Comment: Are you sure you have a  column called `canelledby`. It looks like it's missing a c.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to round Price to 2 decimals?